# Can a BLE Master act as GATT server?

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, esp32

I am trying to get iPhone's Location and Navigation service with ESP32 via BLE.
but there are no example online (I think...I cannot find any).
I mean something like this

- ESP32  ->    BLE peripheral
- iPhone ->    BLE Master

- iPhone connect to ESP32

- ESP32  ->    GATT client - request LN service
- iPhone ->    GATT server - provide GPS signal

- ESP32 get GATT server from iPhone, which is the GPS lat and lag (maybe).

is it feasible to do that ?

Just a Yes/No is okay..
but I also want some links and references that I can learn from them !
thank you so much !

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  I would answer 'Yes' to your question if your phone supports the [Location and Navigation Profile](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/specs/location-and-navigation-profile-1-0/) and -[Service](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/specs/location-and-navigation-service-1-0/).